# How to group data by time interval?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my table:

```
SNO ID  TimeRecorded             LAT          LON      STATE    SPEED

7   0   2015-05-16 12:54:09.000 22.63006    88.362144   NULL    0
8   0   2015-05-16 12:55:09.000 22.63006    88.362144   NULL    0
9   1   2015-05-16 13:01:09.000 22.63006    88.362144   NULL    0
10  1   2015-05-16 13:05:09.000 22.63006    88.362144   NULL    0
```

How to select only 1 record of 1 hour?, I want to select like this:

```
7   0   2015-05-16 12:54:09.000 22.63006    88.362144   NULL    0 and
10  1   2015-05-16 13:05:09.000 22.63006    88.362144   NULL    0
```

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to get SNO 10 in your example? Are you wanting the first record in the hour? The question isn't very clear

Comment: @christian Barron , this is location report and the vehicle speed is normally 5 km/hr so i want only one record of each hour ,that is any one...

Answer (score 2):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cast(timerecorded as date), datepart(hour, timerecorded)
                                order by timerecorded
                               ) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  this returns the first record of each hours.  If you actually want an arbitrary record, you can use `order by newid()` rather than `order by timerecorded`.